# How should I deal with properties inside anonymous functions inside javascript classes?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to object-oriented javascript so maybe I got the terminology wrong.

I have a javascript class that looks like this.

```
var parsesearch = {
    init: function(selector){
        this.selector = $(selector);
        this.count = $(selector).length;
    },
    loopresluts: function(selector){
        this.delay = 350
        this.selector.each(function(indexInArray) {
            parsesearch.announcementID = parsesearch.selector.find('[headers=h-diarienummer] a').text();
            //opening the pages with a delay
            setTimeout( function () {
                console.log(parsesearch.announcementID)
            //adding delay for every itteration.
            }, indexInArray * parsesearch.delay);
        });
    }
}
```

Inside loopresults I have an anonymous function. Inside that function i can't use "this" to reference the properties, but rather use parsesearch."propertyname" I assume that if I instance more than one version of parsesearch, this will cause trouble. Is there a better way to do it? If I use only one instance of the class, would this be considered bad practice, in that case why?

Comment: That's not a class, it most closely resembles a singleton instance which is the way one can get away without doing in OOP in OOP languages actually :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoa so many questions. Let's take it step by step. When you started with

```
var parsesearch = { ...
```

you did singleton, so you can't basicly do more instances of parsesearch. You have just one instance and its functions, thats all.

> If I use only one instance of the class, would this be concidered bad practice, in that case why?

It depends what is its purpose. If you will extend this "widget" and you will add something like options and other stuff + **you will want use more widgets on one site**, then you will probably need more instances. Till then, it is ok to have only one instance and you can keep it like it is.

About `this` question, I basicly agree with *zaquest* and *Thanassis_K* answers. You can use `call`, `apply` native functions or jQuery `proxy` function to change `this` of desired function. Also `var self = this` is very common practise. Then `self` is variable of namespace. Anyway, for some reson all answers here are avoiding prototype, which should be used here, becouse if you declare functions as simple object properties, then they are redeclared with every new instance, which is waste...

My solution for more instances

```
var ParseSearch = function (selector) {
    this.selector = $(selector);
    this.count = $(selector).length;
    this.delay = 350;
}

// you dont need init here... 

ParseSearch.prototype.loopresluts = function(){
    this.selector.each($.proxy(function(indexInArray) {
        this.announcementID = this.selector.find('[headers=h-diarienummer] a')
                                           .text();
        //opening the pages with a delay
        setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
            console.log(this.announcementID)
        //adding delay for every itteration.
        }, this), indexInArray * this.delay);
    }, this));
}

var firstParser = new ParseSearch('div');
firstParser.loopresluts();
```

Comment: I don't know why many instances of this would be required, these should be just merged into a single function call because that's how it is used, you never do anything with the object except call that one method and throw it away, that's a red flag where a single function simplification is warranted.  Because of the hardcoded string selector the context of this class is extremely unreusable too. But +1 for the answer itself as prototype is how you get full benefits of Javascript object model.

Comment: Yes I agree with everything you just said. I expected that he is going to extend it with more behaviors, so I did this like that. Also I could write it even better, but it could appear too complicated for a "newbie". So let him post another question ;) 
PS: thx for edit

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is using closures

```
var parsesearch = {
    init: function(selector){
        this.selector = $(selector);
        this.count = $(selector).length;
    },
    loopresluts: function(selector){
        var self = this;
        this.delay = 350
        this.selector.each(function(indexInArray) {
            self.announcementID = self.selector.find('[headers=h-diarienummer] a').text();
            //opening the pages with a delay
            setTimeout( function () {
                console.log(self.announcementID)
            //adding delay for every itteration.
            }, indexInArray * self.delay);
        });
    }
}
```

or, since you already using `jQuery` you can use `jQuery.proxy`

```
var parsesearch = {
    init: function(selector){
        this.selector = $(selector);
        this.count = $(selector).length;
    },
    loopresluts: function(selector){
        this.delay = 350
        this.selector.each($.proxy(function(indexInArray) {
            this.announcementID = this.selector.find('[headers=h-diarienummer] a').text();
            //opening the pages with a delay
            setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
                console.log(this.announcementID)
            //adding delay for every itteration.
            }, this), indexInArray * this.delay);
        }, this));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use binding, don't use `self` any more.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify it to the following:

```
 var parsesearch = (function () {
    var init = function (selector) {
        this.selector = $(selector);
        this.count = $(selector).length;
    }
    var loopresluts = function (selector) {
        var self = this; // self now refers to that function only
        this.delay = 350
        this.selector.each(function (indexInArray) {
            parsesearch.announcementID = parsesearch.selector.find('[headers=h-diarienummer] a').text();
            //opening the pages with a delay
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log(parsesearch.announcementID)
                //adding delay for every itteration.
            }, indexInArray * parsesearch.delay);
        });
    }
    return {
        init: init,
        loopresluts: loopresluts
    }
});

// create a single instance of your object
var parseS = parsesearch();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just use a variable to hold the current instance (this), than it will be in scope for the anonymous functions to use.

```
loopresluts: function(selector){
    this.delay = 350;
    var scoped = this;
    this.selector.each(function(indexInArray) {
        scoped.announcementID = parsesearch.selector.find('[headers=h-diarienummer] a').text();
        //opening the pages with a delay
        setTimeout( function () {
            console.log(scoped.announcementID)
        //adding delay for every itteration.
        }, indexInArray * scoped.delay);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Bind Method

You can bind a function to an object, e.g., `this`

```
var parsesearch = {
    init: function(selector){
        this.selector = $(selector);
        this.count = $(selector).length;
    },
    loopresluts: function(selector){
        this.delay = 350
        this.selector.each((function(indexInArray) {
            this.announcementID = this.selector.find('[headers=h-diarienummer] a').text();
            //opening the pages with a delay
            setTimeout( function () {
                console.log(this.announcementID)
            //adding delay for every itteration.
            }, indexInArray * this.delay);
        }).bind(this));
    }
}
```

### Scope Method

By declaring a local variable that references `this`, you can then use that variable inside nested functions.

```
var parsesearch = {
    ...
    loopresluts: function(selector){
        var p = this;
        this.delay = 350
        this.selector.each(function(indexInArray) {
            p.announcementID = p.selector.find('[headers=h-diarienummer] a').text();
            //opening the pages with a delay
            setTimeout( function () {
                console.log(p.announcementID)
            //adding delay for every itteration.
            }, indexInArray * p.delay);
        });
    }
}
```